# Overriding parent theme javascript from child theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, themes, customization

My parent theme has a script in \includes\js\custom.js, and I am trying to override this from my child theme. I can see from my parent theme that it is en-queued using this code: (I've trimmed some non-relevant lines of wp_enqueue_script() calls.)

```
function my_deregister_scripts() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/js/jquery.min.js', false, '1.6.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/js/custom.js', false, '1.0');
        if ( is_singular() && get_option('thread_comments') ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
```

At first , I thought I could simply add some code into my own child functions.php like this:

```
function custom_script_fix()
{
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-custom' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child-jquery-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/includes/js/custom.js', false, '1.0');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_script_fix' );
```

but then I read in the codex that nowadays, the child functions.php is run immediately before the parent functions.php. This means that I am dequeueing something that will obly be enqueued again in the parent functions.php. This results in my script being loaded first, followed by the parent script:

[image: As you can see, the child script loads, then the parent.]

So, how would I do this without modifying the parent theme in any way?

Comment: Could you try specifying the load priority?

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91961/hook-wp-enqueue-scripts-priority-has-no-effect

Comment: I figured it out, thanks ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By simply registering the script and using the same handle that is being used in the parent theme, it takes precedence. Thus when the parent theme gets around to enqueueing its own version, the handle is already allocated, and it enqueues the override instead.

```
function custom_script_fix()
{
    // use same handle as parent theme to override ('jquery-custom')
    wp_register_script('jquery-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/includes/js/custom.js', false, '1.0');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_script_fix' );
```

The description on [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) specifies it won't replace the registered version. You may need to set a lower `$priority` on [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) to ensure your override script is registered first.

Comment: I found that `wp_register_script()` alone is sufficient, as later calls to that or `wp_register_script()` will not replace the override. It also means any script overridden this way will only be included if the original would have been.

Comment: @Walf solution was enough for me as well